# javascript vs PHP function

Tags: php, javascript, function

this is `substr()` function in PHP and JavaScript

```
JavaScript syntax:
string.substr(start,length)

PHP syntax:
substr(string,start,length)
```

in PHP to create this function, we do this

```
PHP:
function substr(string,start,length){}
```

how to create function like JavaScript syntax above in JavaScript?

```
JavaScript:
function substr(start,length){}
```

this javascript function will not exactly the same as it's syntax, and it creates a function like PHP does. i dont know where to put `string` in this js function in order to be similar to the original one...

Comment: I wonder if I understood the question correctly :)

Comment: You **really shouldn't** get rid of object-orientation in JavaScript just because most PHP functions are not object-oriented. Using the `.substr(start, len)` method on a string is **much cleaner** than calling a global function and passing the string as a regular function argument.

Comment: @ThiefMaster :my question above is just an example... i dont know how to create a function that require a variable before the function... in PHP all the variable is placed in '()' like this... doSomething(var1,var2,var3) but, in js one of the variable could be placed before the function, like this... var1.doSomething(var2,var3) see what i mean?...

Comment: in the other word, how to create OOP function in JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the substr function would be defined like this:

```
String.prototype.substr = function (start, length) {
    ...
}
```

You simply add functions to the String.prototype object to add functions to JavaScript string objects.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
function substr(string,start,length){
    return string.substr(start,length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** If you just want to know how to create a non-OOP `substr()` function:

```
function substr(str, start, len) {
    return str.substr(start, len);
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

`length === undefined` if you omit the argument.

If you want to give it a default value, you can use something like this:

```
if(length === undefined) { length = string.length; }
```

(this would set `length` to the length of the passed string if omitted)

You can also access the number of arguments which have been actually passed via `arguments.length`

Comment: thanks, but it's not about length arg, i just dont understand how to create a function which is similar to js syntax abve... the string arg is placed before the function, unlike php function...